# Database trouble deploying django app to amazon beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to deploy my Django application to AWS beanstalk. For this I was following this tutorial:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

However, when I use deploy the app using `eb create`, I get a MySQL error

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I am guessing this is because I haven't done any database configuration (the document above doesn't mention a configuration step even once). So, I tried to add an RDS database using this guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html.

Now, I am getting the error that

```
RDS requires that you have a subnet selected in at least two Availability Zones.
```

When I tried to create this subnets, other issues involving VPN's etc crop up. Can someone please help me get a simple django app up and running on the aws? 
Thanks!

Comment: Any one who can please help?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using elastic beanstalk,do not create separate RDS. You can use the AWS Console to deploy the django application.
Choose the RDS configuration while deploying the application and the subnet settings are all taken care by it self

Answer (score 0):

Create the database as you create the app.

```
eb create --database --database.engine mysql --region eu-west-1
```

**Update**:

You can set database user and password like this:

```
eb create --database --database.engine mysql --database.password <password> --database.username <username> --region eu-west-1
```

Here are all available options.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html

Comment: How to set the password, username etc for the database?

Comment: It will ask you through the CLI if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have HOST = 'localhost' in your settings.py. Django will try to connect via Unix socket to Mysql. You probably want to connect to MySQL via TCP.

Inside the DATABASES dict in settings.py:
Set the HOST to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to create subnet as described here,

Create a DB subnet group

Open the Amazon RDS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/.

In the navigation pane, click Subnet Groups.

Click Create DB Subnet Group.

Click Name, and then type the name of your DB Subnet Group.

Click Description, and then describe your DB Subnet Group.

Next to VPC ID, select the ID of the VPC that you created.

Click the add all the subnets link in the Add Subnet(s) to this Subnet Group section.

When you are finished, click Yes, Create
In the confirmation window, click Close.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo-vpc-rds.html#AWSHowTo-vpc-rds-subnet

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed a fallback to the local sql database. During the development process (eb deploy) the RDS env-vars were not found directly:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
if 'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
    logger.error('Loggger: RDS!')
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    logger.error('Loggger: Local!')
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```